# Is it possible to create a python standalone script that is NOT an executable?

Tags: python, software-distribution

I'm looking for a way I can package a tool I've built for use by my colleagues. In order to run it requires modules that are currently only found on my own workstation. Adding the modules to other workstations is not possible because it's explicitly prohibited.

So far I've been unable to locate any way to accomplish my goal without using a module or other software that converts the script into an exe.

My work-site has strict rules for executable software. I am prohibited from creating anything that requires installation, makes any changes to the registry, and/or has exe as its native file extension.

I'm hoping someone here might know a way to get around this restriction while still adhering to that policy. Bending or breaking these rules, even for a moment, would be met with harsh consequences for myself.

Comment: I'm confused... the modules require installation, make changes to the registry or have exe as the file extension?

Comment: Escalate the problem.

Comment: If your work-site has strict rules for executable software, that more than likely includes ANY form of third party external program. Just because you don't need to install the python script or make changes to the registry, doesn't mean your job wont fire you or your colleagues because you found a loophole to get some non-supported software running on the machines

Comment: Question: Does your work-site have a python installation by default? Or are you looking to get everything working on a machine with no python installation?

Comment: If the 'standalone script' is in some form a benefit to you and your colleagues, in relation to your work, why not show your manager and ask if you can get it installed? - You'll receive a nice pat on the back

Comment: @AK47, Python 2.7.8 is installed by default. We are allowed to create scripts for each other, but we are only able to use the modules currently installed on our baseline. The only reason I'm different is that I am authorized to use a different workstation that has access to more tools.

Comment: Why dont you just copy the source files of the python modules you are missing? Most of the python modules are opensource

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Python problem. It's a problem with your company policies.

You simply cannot accomplish what you want to do with those policies, and if you do find a way, it will most likely violate the policies anyway.

You need to talk to a manager.